# struggle with Read CSV file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a CSV file that has text only; for this file, first, I wrote all the text in Notepad and copied and pasted it into Excel, and then I saved the Excel in CSV format

I tried to read it in Python, and I got the results:

```
#csvdata=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/SBSC.csv')
data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/SBSC.csv', encoding= 'unicode_escape')
data
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure about encoding='unicode_escape'...vs .e.g. encoding='utf-8'?

Comment: Post the **text** of the CSV file, not an image.  Also, Notepad is perfectly capable of writing a CSV file.  Copying to Excel and re-saving as a CSV is not needed.  Make sure the encoding used to save the file in Notepad is the encoding used to read the CSV in Python.

Answer (score 1):

The NaN representation ("not a number"), which defines missing values or data according to the pandas documentation, may arise from several different reasons, probably related to the formatting/enconding of the CSV file. These are some of the things I've checked when experienced similar issues reading CSV files on Python:

- Excel may try to automatically detect the delimiter of a text file
  when you open it and save it as CSV, but it may not be able to
  properly do so if there are non-standard characters or line breaks on
  the source file. You could fix it specifying in Python the `delimiter` parameter explicitly, as you did with the `encoding` parameter.

```python
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/SBSC.csv', delimiter=',', enconding='utf-8')
```

- It may also be a good idea to check the encoding you are using on the Notepad, which can be checked on the Save As dialog as seen below, and experiment with it:

[image]

- You could try opening the CSV file in a text editor and make sure the lines and cells are properly delimited by commas and check if the file contains any non-standard characters or line breaks. The line breaks may be different if the file was created in a different operating system (Windows, Mac, or Linux), an issue you could solve adding to the previous code the `newline` parameter:

```python
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/SBSC.csv', delimiter=',', enconding='utf-8', newline='\r\n')
```

- If none of these work, you could try preprocessing the CSV file manually to ensure it is properly formatted, like using a short subset sample of data.